# Where to apply $\nabla$ operator when taking curl of a cross product?

Tags: electrostatics, vectors, differentiation, vector-fields, mathematics

In my EM class we went over $$\nabla\times \frac{\vec{d}\times \vec{r}}{r^3}$$ which apparently can be breaken down to $$r(d\cdot \nabla)\frac{1}{r^3}-d(r\cdot\nabla)\frac{1}{r^3}+\frac{\nabla\times(d\times r)}{r^3}.$$ From now on the solution is clear, but how did the two first terms emerge? I see that there is a similarity with the BAC-CAB rule, but I've understood that there is no reason for BAC-CAB to hold when dealing with nabla, it just might in some cases. I would love a  rigorous explanation as to how the split into 3 terms happened. Oh and $\vec{d}$ is a constant and $\vec{r}$ the radius vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Jackson's "Classical Electrodynamics"  you find how to derive lots of results like this. On the inside cover pages there's a lookup table [[Jackson]](https://www.scribd.com/doc/260715311/Classical-Electrodynamics-J-D-Jackson) where they are summarized, this one in fact is present, when you absorb the $1/r^3$  into one of the vectors in your expression, e.g. ${\bf d}  \rightarrow {\bf d}/r^3$ or ${\bf r}  \rightarrow {\bf r}/r^3$.

Of course you can try to derive the result yourself by starting with the definition of the cross product and the curl using the Levi-Civita symbol $\epsilon_{ijk}$ and the Einstein notation convention of summing over repeated indices:
$$
({\bf a} \times {\bf b})\,_i = \epsilon_{ijk} \, a_j \, b_k
$$
$$
(\nabla \times {\bf v})\,_i = \epsilon_{ijk} \, \partial_j \, v_k
$$
But it might be better to first look up how these things are done for a few examples.

Comment: Yep, and using Levi-Civita symbols also makes it easy to generalize the result to n-dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Any product of fields, vectors, tensors, expands into a vector of any dimensions with elements of sums of products. By this simple fact the product rule can be applied to any combinations of cross and scalar products.

The application of the product rule to the product of $f(\mathbf{r}) = r^{-3}$ and a vector yields, respecting the left to right-order of derivatives and functions,

$$\nabla\times \left(f(\mathbf{r})\left(\mathbf{d} \times \mathbf{r}\right) \right) = f\nabla\times \left(\mathbf{d} \times \mathbf{r}\right) + \nabla f \times \left(\mathbf{d} \times \mathbf{r} \right) \\ = f \nabla \times \left(\mathbf{d} \times \mathbf{r}\right)+ \mathbf{d} \left(\nabla f \cdot \mathbf{r}\right) -  \mathbf{r} \left(\nabla f \cdot \mathbf{d} \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Differential symbols   and integral symbols are local variables. With a mix of noncommutative differential symbols and noncommutative products, the best way is to introduce local symbols for  $\nabla_x$ to fix the object of differentiation and to unify the position vector symbol after expansion of products.

$$\nabla_x \times \left( f (\vec x)\ \vec d  \times  \vec x \right) = 
f(\vec x) \nabla_x \times \left(  \vec d \times \vec x \right) + \nabla_y \left(  f(\vec y)  \vec d \times \vec x \right) |_{y\to x} $$
$$=
f(\vec x) \nabla_x \times \left(  \vec d \times \vec x \right)+  \vec d \  \left( \vec x \cdot \nabla_x f(\vec x) \right)  -
\vec x  \ \left( \vec d \cdot \nabla_x f(\vec x) \right)  $$

A third way is to use a $\nabla_{x_i}$ working to the right on the i-th occurence of x in a product only,  and to add all terms in the end, justified by the general law of linear approximations in power series expansions in higher dimensions, finally projecting the result to the diagonal, all $x_i$ identified.

$$\nabla_x \times \left( f (\vec x)\ \vec d  \times  \vec x \right) =
\nabla_{x_1} \times \left( f (\vec x_1)\ \vec d  \times  \vec x \right)+
\nabla_{x_2} \times \left( f (\vec x)\ \vec d  \times  \vec x_2 \right)$$